# How do I isolate my file system data from another system root?

Tags: security, sudo, account-restrictions, access-control

I have a linux machine(kubuntu 13.04)
A my friend asked me give him an account with being able to use `sudo`. So, I made an account for him and put the account in `/etc/group` for him to use `sudo`
I don't care he installs or manages any programs but don't want him to access my home folder `/home/myaccount` and its sub folders. How can I do this?

Comment: Read the manpage for sudoers: `man 5 sudoers`

Comment: You can encrypt your home or if you have the space and resources you could create a virtual machine that he could use and not have any access to your host machine.

Comment: If you encrypt your home directory, he can obtain the encryption key through logging or RAM analysis. Virtualizing his environment is your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you can not. If he has "full root privileges" (and the needed knowledge), he'll can circumvent any limitation you can impose him.

Try to reverse your approach: He needs **full** root privileges? Why? Really? Give him `sudo` privileges only to minimal required set of command. E.g. To install an application by package management, he needs only to run `rpm` (or `yum` or `apt-get`) as root, not any program.

As stated by @Evan-Teitelman, even this could be dangerous. In `sudoers` file you can define even which command parameters a user can use, so you could let him use only an high-level command-line interface of the package manager (as `apt-get` or `zipper`) and let him install the software only from official repositories.

P.S. In any case, if he reboots the machine using a live-cd, he'll can read anything unless you encrypt the home file-system.

Comment: `He needs full root privileges?` No, he just want to manage server program. ex) install nginx, setting smtp, samba, web application, rutorrent and so on. I don't care about that, if only he can not access my home folder.

Comment: Giving him access to a package installer would give him a means to install a root-owned setuid shell.

Comment: @Evan-Teitelman, You are right :-/